# Skip final review page after paypal express checkout - Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm working on this Hotel website project for one of my clients.

Website: http[:]//www[.]dreamshotelmaldives[.]com/

CMS: Wordpress /

Plugin: Woocommerce / AWEBooking

Payment-gateway: https[:]//www[dot]woothemes[dot]com/products/paypal-express/

The website's reservation module is fully integrated with a Third Party Plugin called, AWEBooking. and i use WooCommerce for the checkout process and an additional extension plugin from woothemes to integrate the Paypal Express Checkout option.

Problem: Well the problem is after you select a room and head to checkout it directs to paypal sandbox cgi (since using sandbox credentials for testing), it REDIRECTS TO AN UNWANTED PAGE, SEE BELOW SCREENSHOT.

[UNWANTED CART PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEdUl.jpg)

What I want to do is skip that page and head right away to the thank you page! please see below screenshot,

[WHAT I WANT TO DISPLAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JJG6.jpg)

I've seen that Angeleye paypal vendor plugin has an option to SKIP the final review page, but not this plugin!

Below is a code snippet from the plugin code, file name 'class-wc-gateway-paypal-express.php'

#

```
        // called when the customer is returned from PayPal after authorizing their payment, used for retrieving the customer's checkout details
        case 'get_express_checkout_details':

            // bail if no token
            if ( ! isset( $_GET['token'] ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // get token to retrieve checkout details with
            $token = esc_attr( $_GET['token'] );

            try {

                $response = $this->get_api()->get_express_checkout_details( $token );

                // save customer information to session
                WC()->session->paypal_express_checkout = array(
                    'token'            => $token,
                    'shipping_details' => $response->get_shipping_details(),
                    'order_note'       => $response->get_note_text(),
                    'payer_id'         => $response->get_payer_id(),
                );

                // ensures PPE is selected at checkout
                WC()->session->chosen_payment_method = get_class( $this );

                // redirect customer to checkout
                wp_redirect( WC()->get_checkout_url() );

            } catch ( Exception $e ) {

                $this->add_debug_message( $e->getMessage(), 'error' );

                wc_add_notice( __( 'An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment.', WC_PayPal_Express::TEXT_DOMAIN ), 'error' );

                wp_redirect( $cancel_url );
            }

            exit;
    }
}
```

#

I THINK, what i got to call is for woocommerce endpoint url "$order>get_checkout_order_received_url();" please help me how to include this code and SKIP the UNWANTED PAGE!

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME!
AISAR

Comment: Why not just use the angelleye [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/) plugin you mentioned?  It will give you the specific option you're looking for as well as a lot of other options that the Woo version does not provide.

Comment: Yes exactly and i tried that plugin but it gives me below notice in the payment method section " Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your state " and i couldn'd find anyway to solve that around the forums and here.

So i gave up and took my chances with Woothemes addons Plugin Paypal Express, it seems to work in the checkout page and can make a sandbox payment, i've tested it and its working good. 

Now all i want is to skip the final review page, as it does in the angelleye plugin. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You won't be able to get it done in the Woo plugin without customizing it with code.  It sounds like you just didn't have one setting configured correctly in the PayPal for WooCommerce plugin.  You have to specify that Express Checkout should be included in the regular list of gateways on the WooCommerce checkout page.

Comment: Yes of course we need to customize the Woo Plugin code. Please see below commit fix of Angel Eye Plugin.

https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-woocommerce/commit/bee91116013a41974c3574d91f05e09830751446

Please help me to include the above code for the skip final review page in the Woothemes plugin i'm using. That's the exact code to skip the final review page, however i don't where to include the codes in this plugin.

Please help me out.

Comment: Doing it that way is not recommended.  Next you update their plugin you would lose your custom changes.  It would need to be done as a custom extension to their plugin.  You would really save yourself a lot of time and frustration by just using the angelleye plugin instead.  It's the exact same thing, but gives you what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay thank you for getting by. As I've said i would love to use the open source AngellEye Plugin, which is much more feasible BUT ONLY IF anybody could help me out to get the fix for this "there's no payment method available for your state" at the payment method section in checkout page, when the customer places order.

Comment: Yes, as I said before, that would happen if you don't have it configured correctly.  If you [submit a ticket here](https://www.angelleye.com/support) and provide temporary login credentials for your site they'll configure it for you.